# Time Displacement in Blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, add-on, video-sequence-editor

So I have said this earlier, but I love watching Adobe After Effects tutorials, and recreating them in blender. But I have this problem that has happened in a few tutorials now. Its where people use the Time Displacement Modifier. It looks like a really handy modifier, and I am almost certain that it can be recreated for blender. The question I have is: Does an addon already exist? or do I/we need to make it so? Thanks for your help!

EDIT: For those who don't know what time displacement does, watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCZ3MqXOfYQ

Comment: It would be useful if you could give some information about what the 'Time Displacement Modifier' actually does, for those of use unfamiliar with After Effects.

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible in Blender, or hasn't been tried. You may be able to reproduce the effect, but you will have to develop the process in Blender yourself.

Comment: I played around with trying to get this effect in the compositor a while ago but was unsuccessful. I think I decided that the only way to access multiple frames at once was via a lot of image sequence nodes with different offsets. So this would be possible, but you'd need a separate image sequence node for every "time pixel", or every horizontal bar in the case of the vertical gradient. Which means you'd certainly want to use python to add all those nodes :P

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this is not possible in Blender, or hasn't been tried properly. You may be able to reproduce the effect, but you will have to develop the process in Blender yourself.

Other people have attempted to do this, but not successfully. As Gandalf said:

> I played around with trying to get this effect in the compositor a while ago but was unsuccessful. I think I decided that the only way to access multiple frames at once was via a lot of image sequence nodes with different offsets. So this would be possible, but you'd need a separate image sequence node for every "time pixel", or every horizontal bar in the case of the vertical gradient. Which means you'd certainly want to use python to add all those nodes :P